# BABEL Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /X/Y/Z/index.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, nuxt.js, babel-loader

In my nuxt project I am getting this error, where I used typescript. After some research I found that I have to set the compact as false in '.babelrc' file but the problem is I am not seeing any '.babelrc' file in my project. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone still facing the problem you should upgrade your node version. Thank you.